# Is there something like tuple in .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I need some data type like `List<int , int , int ,string , int >`.
Of course I can implement , but is there something built in .net 3.5.

Thanks .

Comment: Usually you would create a wrapper class for your <int, int, int, string, int> and then have a List<WrapperClass>. If you need performance seeking on one of the fields, then Dictionary<field, WrapperClass>

Comment: Yes in the system lib: Tuple<int, int, string, int> tuple; Will work. Just enter the values in the constructor. But you can also create your own class or struct just for holding data. -1 because you should have found this really fast by looking yourself.

Comment: @MrFox where in the `System` lib 2.0/3.5 you can find `Tuple<>`?

Comment: +1-ing the question to make up for MrFox's -1 (which is incorrect, not to mention rude).  System.Tuple only occurs in .NET 4.0 and later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there isn't anything in .NET 3.5. But rather than `Tuple`, have you considered implementing your own simple type which encapsulates the members you need? Usually that ends up giving more readable code than `Tuple` anyway - especially when you've got quite a lot of members, most of which have the same types.

It's a lot easier to understand:

```
foo(sale.AdultTickets, sale.ChildTickets, ...);
```

than

```
foo(sale.Item1, sale.Item2, ...);
```

It's a little bit more work, but it needn't be *much* more.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen a simple Tuple implementation for C# in [Real World Functional Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988924) from Jon Skeet and Tomas Petricek. Until v4 there was no implementation provided.

Code can be downloaded at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/realworldfp/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3674

Answer (score 3):

I implemented my own:

```
public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
    public T3 Item3 { get; set; }
    public T4 Item4 { get; set; }
    public T5 Item5 { get; set; }

    public Tuple(T1 Item1, T2 Item2, T3 Item3, T4 Item4, T5 Item5)
    {
        this.Item1 = Item1;
        this.Item2 = Item2;
        this.Item3 = Item3;
        this.Item4 = Item4;
        this.Item5 = Item5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the Tuple out of the F# distribution. Download the Redistributable package from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829875(VS.100).aspx; reference FSharp.Core in your C# projcet and then:

```
namespace FSharpTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Tuple<string> aTuple;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK 3.5 doesn't support Tuples.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there isn't. There's the KeyValuePair for tuples but no built in triples, quadruples etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not per se, but an implementation of the Tuple<> generic class(es) is not too hard, albeit cumbersome for all the "overloads".

There is a [project on codeplex](http://systemtuples.codeplex.com/releases/view/43079), but I don't know how mature it is.

Answer (score -2):

You can use my implementation :)

```
public class Tuple
{
    public static Tuple<T1> Create<T1>(T1 t1)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1>(t1);
    }

    public static Tuple<T1, T2> Create<T1, T2>(T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2>(t1, t2);
    }

    public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3> Create<T1, T2, T3>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3>(t1, t2, t3);
    }

    static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>(t1, t2, t3, t4);
    }

    static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4, T5 t5)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5);
    }

    static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4, T5 t5, T6 t6)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6);
    }

    static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4, T5 t5, T6 t6, T7 t7)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7);
    }

    static Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4, T5 t5, T6 t6, T7 t7, TRest Rest)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest>(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, Rest);
    }
}

public class Tuple<T1> : Tuple
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }

    public Tuple(T1 Item1)
    {
        this.Item1 = Item1;
    }
}

public class Tuple<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }

    public Tuple(T1 Item1, T2 Item2)
    {
        this.Item1 = Item1;
        this.Item2 = Item2;
    }
}

public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3>
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
    public T3 Item3 { get; set; }

    public Tuple(T1 Item1, T2 Item2, T3 Item3)
    {
        this.Item1 = Item1;
        this.Item2 = Item2;
        this.Item3 = Item3;
    }
}

public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4>
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
    public T3 Item3 { get; set; }
    public T4 Item4 { get; set; }

    public Tuple(T1 Item1, T2 Item2, T3 Item3, T4 Item4)
    {
        this.Item1 = Item1;
        this.Item2 = Item2;
        this.Item3 = Item3;
        this.Item4 = Item4;
    }
}

public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
    public T3 Item3 { get; set; }
    public T4 Item4 { get; set; }
    public T5 Item5 { get; set; }

    public Tuple(T1 Item1, T2 Item2, T3 Item3, T4 Item4, T5 Item5)
    {
        this.Item1 = Item1;
        this.Item2 = Item2;
        this.Item3 = Item3;
        this.Item4 = Item4;
        this.Item5 = Item5;
    }
}

public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
    public T3 Item3 { get; set; }
    public T4 Item4 { get; set; }
    public T5 Item5 { get; set; }
    public T6 Item6 { get; set; }

    public Tuple(T1 Item1, T2 Item2, T3 Item3, T4 Item4, T5 Item5, T6 Item6)
    {
        this.Item1 = Item1;
        this.Item2 = Item2;
        this.Item3 = Item3;
        this.Item4 = Item4;
        this.Item5 = Item5;
        this.Item6 = Item6;
    }
}

public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7>
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
    public T3 Item3 { get; set; }
    public T4 Item4 { get; set; }
    public T5 Item5 { get; set; }
    public T6 Item6 { get; set; }
    public T7 Item7 { get; set; }

    public Tuple(T1 Item1, T2 Item2, T3 Item3, T4 Item4, T5 Item5, T6 Item6, T7 Item7)
    {
        this.Item1 = Item1;
        this.Item2 = Item2;
        this.Item3 = Item3;
        this.Item4 = Item4;
        this.Item5 = Item5;
        this.Item6 = Item6;
        this.Item7 = Item7;
    }
}

public class Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, TRest>
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
    public T3 Item3 { get; set; }
    public T4 Item4 { get; set; }
    public T5 Item5 { get; set; }
    public T6 Item6 { get; set; }
    public T7 Item7 { get; set; }
    public TRest Rest { get; set; }

    public Tuple(T1 Item1, T2 Item2, T3 Item3, T4 Item4, T5 Item5, T6 Item6, T7 Item7, TRest Rest)
    {
        this.Item1 = Item1;
        this.Item2 = Item2;
        this.Item3 = Item3;
        this.Item4 = Item4;
        this.Item5 = Item5;
        this.Item6 = Item6;
        this.Item7 = Item7;
        this.Rest  = Rest;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the answers bellow and see the quantity of code and the readability.

Comment: @bitoiu are you aware that this the same as the microsoft implementation? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @bitoiu i have checked the answers below but non of them are compatible with the microsoft implementation, maybe this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link help you clarify what i wrote.